# Hiding text elements in D3 chord diagram

Tags: d3.js, chord-diagram

Similar to [this example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/chord.html):

[image]

I have a function that highlights the chords linked to the selected group and hides all unrelated chords:

```
function fade() {
    return function(d, i) {
        svg.selectAll("path.chord")
        .filter(function(d) {
            return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i;
        })
        .style("visibility", "hidden");
    };
}
```

I was trying to extend this so that it not only hides the chords, but also the text labels for  groups that are not connected to the currently selected group.

Is it possible to combine these two operations into a single function that I pass to `.on("mouseover",[function])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select with a logical OR like this:

```
svg.selectAll("path.chord, text.groupLabel")
```

see the [documentation on selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) for more details